# Display dropdown selections based on previous selections in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to RShiny. I want to populate RShiny dropdowns based previous selections. 
For E.g. in the image below, 
User first selects the 'route', upon which 'schedule' drop-down gets populated, then user selects 'schedule', then 'trip' drop-down is populated and user selects a 'trip' input.

[image]

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library("plotly")
library(lubridate)
require(rgl)
require(akima)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data335 <<- read.csv("final335eonly.csv")
#data335[c(2,4,5,8,9,10)] = lapply(data335[c(2,4,5,8,9,10)], as.numeric)


routes <<- as.vector(unique(data335[,'route_no']))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demand Analysis"),

  selectInput("routeInput", "Select the route", choices = routes),
  selectInput("scheduleInput", "Select the schedule", c("")),
  selectInput("tripInput", "Select the trip", c(""))



)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$routeInput,
    {

      x <<- input$routeInput
      updateSelectInput(session, "scheduleInput",
                        choices = data335[data335$route_no == input$routeInput, ]$schedule_no,selected = tail(x, 1)
                        )
      }
  )
  observeEvent(input$scheduleInput,
    {
      y <<- input$scheduleInput
      updateSelectInput(session, "tripInput",
                        choices = data335[(data335$route_no == input$routeInput & data335$schedule_no == input$scheduleInput), ]$trip_no,selected = tail(y, 1)
                        )
    }
  )


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The input csv file required is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3vA9tuu5goHUHpHOGM4UjR6eUk):

Whenever I try to run this seemingly simple code, eventhough the UI appears, when I try to select the inputs in dropdown, RShiny crashes.

Can you please let me know what is causing this?

Comment: `<<-` is used for assignment for global variables, as you need to load  `routes` and `data335` only once, so `data335 <- read.csv("final335eonly.csv")` and `routes <- as.vector(unique(data335[,'route_no']))` should fix the issue

Comment: @parth: I tried the changes; doesn't fix the issue. btw, whether we use `<<-` or `=` should not affect because they are outside the Server and UI functions.

Comment: is there any warning or error message in console before the crash ?

Comment: @parth:No error messages in console; what happens is that after selecting the inputs for once or twice, RStudio stops responding .

Comment: try running the localhost url of shiny app, funny thing : even though RStudio doesn't responds, url-app works fine !!

Comment: @parth: can you please upvote the question, so that it catches the attention of other enthusiasts as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157636/discussion-between-kasa-and-parth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are not giving unique values as choices. `data335[data335$route_no == input$routeInput, ]$schedule_no` have duplicate values which causes the crash.

Also, you are selecting the value of `input$routeInput` in your `scheduleInput`, which is not listed in the choice could be another reason for the crash.

Just commenting the two statements and adding unique to your choices resolves the crash.

Also as @parth pointed out in his comments why are you using `<<-` everywhere in your code, it not necessary. Although its not the cause of the crash, until and unless you want to share variables between `sessions` use of `<<-` inside the server is not a good practice.

Here is your code with the commented section with two `selected` arguments commented  and `unique` added that works:

```
library(shiny)
library("plotly")
library(lubridate)
require(rgl)
require(akima)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data335 <<- read.csv("final335eonly.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


routes <<- as.vector(unique(data335[,'route_no']))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demand Analysis"),

  selectInput("routeInput", "Select the route", choices = routes),
  selectInput("scheduleInput", "Select the schedule", c("")),
  selectInput("tripInput", "Select the trip", c(""))



)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$routeInput,
               {

                 x <<- input$routeInput
                 updateSelectInput(session, "scheduleInput",
                                   choices =unique(data335[data335$route_no == input$routeInput, ]$schedule_no),#selected = tail(x, 1)
                 )
               }
  )
  observeEvent(input$scheduleInput,
               {
                 y <<- input$scheduleInput
                 updateSelectInput(session, "tripInput",
                                   choices = unique(data335[(data335$route_no == input$routeInput & data335$schedule_no == input$scheduleInput), ]$trip_no),#selected = tail(y, 1)
                 )
               }
  )


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```